# Format field for my db MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need to write in a database field named Risultato, the score of athletics races.
So sometimes I need to write the score in format seconds and decimal (i.e. 9.75 or 13.46, etc), sometimes I need to write minutes, seconds and decimals like 8:19.08 or 2:08:01 if I have to write hours, minutes and seconds.

Definitely three types of format.

So when I run the script I see that the insert query works for the first one format only, and does not work for the second and third ones.

For field Risultato I chosen utf8_general_ci collation, and a varchar(255) as type.

Comment: How is the script 'not working'? Is it leaving the field empty? Is it not inserting the record at all? Could you include the part of the script that attempts to insert into the database?

Comment: Do you need to perform any operations with Risultato? If so (and even if not), I recommend storing the time as an integer (or bigint) of the smallest standard resolution you need to keep track of - in your examples milliseconds would fit (centiseconds are not supported in mysql). You might then display time as DATE_ADD(0, INTERVAL Risultato MILLISECONDS), letting date_add take care of the arithmetic.

Comment: This is all debatable, actually. Varchar / Text does do the trick, but sorting wise it maybe not the best idea. Next to that, integer is made for numbers, so I would stick with that.

To your problemw ith saving and query, can you show us the code? Do you enter that directly in PHPmyadmin? or have some other way to put your code in? That part is a little vague.